How to enable Terms and conditions in keycloak with kcadmin?
I want to enable Terms and conditions in Authentication -> Required actions -> Terms and Conditions by kcadmin. Is it possible somehow?
I have tryed with something like this:
kcadm.sh update authentication/required-actions -r my_realm -s alias="terms_and_conditions" -s name="Terms and Conditions" -s providerId="terms_and_conditions" -s enabled=true -s defaultAction=true

Finally I found the sollution:
kcadm.sh update authentication/required-actions/TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS -s 'alias=TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS' -s 'name=Terms and Conditions' -s 'providerId=TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS' -s 'enabled=true' -s 'defaultAction=true' -r <your_realm>;

